# how to trigger firstDataRendered on ag-grid in angular?

Tags: angular8, ag-grid

my component has input that gets data
and im selecting the first row with firstDataRendered.
the problem is when the input data changed so the grid not fires the events
how can i trigger the grid events based on my input changes?

```
 <ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  style="width: 100%; height: 500px"
  [rowData]="flights"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowSelection]="'single'"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>

import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnInit,
  SimpleChanges,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Flight } from './model/flight.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-worker-flights-list',
  templateUrl: './worker-flights-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./worker-flights-list.component.css'],
})
export class WorkerFlightsListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() flights: Flight[] = [];
  gridApi: any;
  rendered: boolean;
  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Flight Number', field: 'num' },
    { headerName: 'Origin', field: 'from' },
    { headerName: 'Origin Date', field: 'from_date' },
    { headerName: 'Destination', field: 'to' },
    { headerName: 'Destination Date', field: 'to_date' },
  ];
  constructor() {}
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['flights'] && this.rendered) {
      // this.gridApi.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0).setSelected(true);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  onGridReady(grid: any): void {
    debugger;
    this.gridApi = grid;
  }
  onFirstDataRendered(params: any): void {
    this.rendered = true;
    this.gridApi.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0).setSelected(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event `firstDataRendered` will only be fired the *first* time data is rendered, not every time the data is rendered or updated. See the event definition [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous).

A solution would be to utilize the `rowDataChanged` event like so:

```
onRowDataChanged(params: any): void {
    this.rendered = true;
    params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0).setSelected(true);
  }
```

See demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-4rxi66?file=src/app/app-worker-flights-list/app-worker-flights-list.component.ts)